# Select item from list from span class in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to select an item from a drop down list, this is the HTML portion of it.
Looking to select 'Health Care' from drop down

```
<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 571px; left: 86px;">
<span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--above" dir="ltr" style="width: 232px;">
<span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown" style="display: inline;">
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox"></span>
<span class="select2-results">
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-propertyType-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-rxo5-Apartment" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Apartment</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-s9cp-Agriculture" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Agriculture</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-g6id-Casino" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Casino</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-4b59-Condo" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Condo</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-5ahr-Hotel" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Hotel</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-u5dl-Health Care" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Health Care</li>
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-propertyType-result-eb9i-Industrial" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Industrial</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-5jvx-Land" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Land</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-th7u-Mobile Home" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Mobile Home</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-cm2a-Office" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Office</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-l5wj-Retail" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Retail</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-5e0l-Senior" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Senior</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-cln7-Single-Family" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Single-Family</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-eqt5-Storage" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Storage</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-propertyType-result-7r8v-Special Purpose" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Special Purpose</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">
</li></ul></span></span></span>
```

I've tried numerous times and have had no luck. As you can see in the meantime I have Industrial highlighted. Any help would be great!

Current code I have is:

```
        type_input = '//*[@class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown"]'
        type_input_select = '//*[@id="select2-propertyType-result-ox1c-Health Care"]'
```

```
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(type_input)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(type_input_select).click()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the unordered list has an ID, I would suggest `driver.find_element_by_id` and then search for the text value of list item equal to 'Health Care'.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="select2-propertyType-result-hbbh-Health Care"]"}

Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

First, click the input and click the li element with the text

```
  type_input_select = '//li[contains(text(),"Health Care")]'
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[contains(text(),"Health Care")]"}